# What exactly are validates and has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not asking what are the purposes or what they are doing, these are already explained in other tutorials (e.g., [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)). I feel like these words are some sort of defined methods, potentially from a super class (i.e., `ActiveRecord::Base`), But it makes no sense to call a method/function beyond any method. Or is it a language feature and I should just take these two words as built-in keywords? Are they still in the scope of Ruby or the syntax is from Ruby on Rails framework?

To give you a concrete example:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :email, confirmation: true
    validates :email_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

Comment: They're regular Ruby class methods. You can see where `validates` is defined in [ActiveModel::Validations](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2bb0abbec0e4abe843131f188129a1189b1bf714/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L104), which is `include`d in ActiveRecord::Base.

Comment: I see. To add on, validates is a class method defined in ActiveRecord::Base, reference from http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/. But it still doesn't answer my question: I take the second and third line as function calls, can you make a function call beyond a method?

Comment: They are not function calls, they are method calls, like any other method call. There are no functions in Ruby, only methods. Technically, the Ruby terminology is that they are "message sends". You don't call methods, rather Ruby calls methods for you in reaction to a message send. But you can use the term "method call" and Rubyists will understand you, even if it is not 100% correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, `validates` and `has_many` are normal class methods in Ruby.

With regard to your question "Can you make a [method] call beyond a method?" I feel like the code you cited supplies the answer: Yes.

Unlike some programming languages, in Ruby class and module definitions aren't special unicorns. You can execute any Ruby code inside them. Here's an example:

```
class Foo
  def self.say_goodbye
    puts "Goodbye!"
  end

  puts "Hello!"
  say_goodbye
end
```

Try it yourself to see what it does.

Okay, spoilers: This code creates the class Foo and immediately prints `Hello!` and `Goodbye!`. On the second-to-last line `say_goodbye` is a method call equivalent to `self.say_goodbye`. Since you're inside its class definition, `self` is `Foo`, the class itself, so it's equivalent to `Foo.say_goodbye`.

In the case of `validates` and `has_many`, Rails defines these in modules ([ActiveModel::Validations](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2bb0abbec0e4abe843131f188129a1189b1bf714/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L104) and [ActiveRecord::Associations](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/130dd3da2a2c557185a73afa9e67138691c8e32f/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1258), respectively) that are ultimately `include`d in ActiveRecord::Base. I say "ultimately" because Rails does it somewhat circuitously via its [autoloading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) mechanism, but at its core it's all just plain old Ruby.

Comment: Combine your answer and @Boris Pilgun's answer, I get the whole picture, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Both of them `has_many` and `validates` are methods defined inside of rails gems. They describing properties of rails models (Rails is based on [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) - how model should be validated before saving and how it relates to other models.

Here are definitions: [validates](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L104), [has_many](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1358), and many more...

Answer (score 0):

the names of methods

also, guessing `validates` would add additional methods to associated class

also, guessing both `validates` as well as `has_many` could be considered to employ metaprogramming techniques